# Trying to auto click class using jquery on pageload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hi i am trying to convert this click event to auto click on pageload but it's not working i'm adding this code: jQuery( document ).ready(function() { jQuery(".mystickyelement-contactform").click(); }) but no luck it is not working

```
/* Open tab on Click Event*/             
        $('.mystickyelements-on-click .mystickyelements-social-icon').on( 'click touch', function(event){
            if($(this).parent('li').hasClass("elements-active")) {
                $('.mystickyelements-on-click .elements-active').removeClass("elements-active");
                $(this).parent('li').addClass('elements-active');
            } else {
                $(this).parent('li').removeClass('elements-active');                
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

HTML CODE - As asked the code which chows in browser -- @devlincarnate

```html
<li id="mystickyelements-contact-form" class="mystickyelements-contact-form  element-desktop-on element-mobile-on">
                <span class="mystickyelements-social-icon " style="background-color: rgb(44, 101, 108); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>Campaign Impact</span>


                <div class="element-contact-form">
                  <h3 style="color: #ffffff;">
          Campaign Impact          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="element-contact-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
         </h3>
         <div class="campaign-impact">
           <div data-elementor-type="wp-post" data-elementor-id="560" class="elementor elementor-560" data-elementor-settings="[]">
   <div class="elementor-inner">
    <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
       <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-5f0af99 elementor-section-content-top elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section" data-id="5f0af99" data-element_type="section">
      <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
    <div class="elementor-row">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-1268dd8 elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-id="1268dd8" data-element_type="column" id="campaign-co_1">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-75f2e0b elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-id="75f2e0b" data-element_type="section">
      <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
    <div class="elementor-row">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-de08ce8 col-left-campaign elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column" data-id="de08ce8" data-element_type="column">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-befeeb3 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="befeeb3" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p style="text-align: left;">Events</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-75e963b campaign-co_2 elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column" data-id="75e963b" data-element_type="column">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-38ed594 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="38ed594" data-element_type="widget" id="right-content" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p style="text-align: left;">1</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </section>
    <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-3487153 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-id="3487153" data-element_type="section">
      <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
    <div class="elementor-row">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c3054f0 col-left-campaign elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column" data-id="c3054f0" data-element_type="column">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-03bf014 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="03bf014" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p style="text-align: left;">Social Media Campaigns</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f2488e0 campaign-co_2 elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column" data-id="f2488e0" data-element_type="column">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-72eda5e elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="72eda5e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p style="text-align: left;">4</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </section>
    <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-d8ff7b2 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-id="d8ff7b2" data-element_type="section">
      <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
    <div class="elementor-row">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c5228cd col-left-campaign elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column" data-id="c5228cd" data-element_type="column">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d8ad7fe elementor-shape-circle content-social elementor-widget elementor-widget-social-icons" data-id="d8ad7fe" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="social-icons.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-social-icons-wrapper">
       <a class="elementor-icon elementor-social-icon elementor-social-icon-twitter elementor-repeater-item-9e746ab" href="http://twitter.com/GHS" target="_blank">
     <span class="elementor-screen-only">Twitter</span>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>    </a>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-a2cd569 content-social elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="a2cd569" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">3M Impressions <br>41 M Reach</div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </section>
    <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-2cd794b elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-id="2cd794b" data-element_type="section">
      <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
    <div class="elementor-row">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-e6bae80 col-left-campaign elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column" data-id="e6bae80" data-element_type="column">
   <div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
     <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f14f374 elementor-shape-circle content-social elementor-widget elementor-widget-social-icons" data-id="f14f374" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="social-icons.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-social-icons-wrapper">
       <a class="elementor-icon elementor-social-icon elementor-social-icon-facebook elementor-repeater-item-9e746ab" href="http://facebook.com/globalhealthstrategies" target="_blank">
     <span class="elementor-screen-only">Facebook</span>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>    </a>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-83cab11 content-social elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="83cab11" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
     <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p>57 K Reach</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </section>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </section>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
           </div>
         <p class="mse-form-success-message" id="mse-form-error" style="display:none;"></p>
        </div>
       </li>
```

Comment: We need to see the related HTML because in theory,  it should work.  See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d074xjq9/).

Comment: ya i want that particular tab on page load (can i get your email so i can share the snippet) would appreciate your help can't figure out  @devlincarnate

Comment: You can edit your question and post the relevant HTML code.

Comment: I did please have a look @devlincarnate

Comment: So, jQuery doesn't work with the HTML you posted.  There is no HTML element with class `mystickyelement-on-click'.  Are you sure you don't mean to have a comma between the two classes?  The event triggers when I put a comma between the classes... [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrc4hoya/)